# Python regex list filtering

Tags: python, regex, list

I have a list. I want to filter the contents in the parenthesis '()' into a new list using regex.

```
a = ['avg(time)']
```

using regex want this to

```
a = time.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import re
parathesis_check = re.compile(r'[(]\w+[)]')
parathesis_check.findall('avg(time)')
```

**Result**

```
['(time)']
```

[Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/D6OhU_tb40UWeUC0)